# Using two datatables, group by ID and count, then subtract, then update rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable, checkboxlist

I am using Visual Studio with vb.net, asp.net, and webforms.

I populate two datatables and place some values into two checkboxlists (Populate Available Checkboxlist and Populate Active Checkboxlist). That all works great.

Here is where I am stuck and need help.

**First Step**: In Available, I have a column called ID. The ID values are unique as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. In Active, I have ID which correspond to those, but there can be multiples, such as 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, etc. So what I need to do is COUNT how many of each ID is in Active. For example, in 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4 there are three 1's, one 2, one 3, and one 4. How can I do that?

**Second Step**: After I do that, I need to do subtraction. I need to see what MaxAccount is (such as 5) and subtract it from Step 1. So for example, if MaxAccount is 5 and I have three 1's, then 5 - 3 = 2.

**Third Step**: I need to update AccountTotal with the value from step 2.

You can see my attempt to code this at UpdateAccountTotal() but just get stuck.

Update AccountTotal

```
Private Function UpdateAccountTotal() As DataTable
    Dim dtDefaultAvailable As New DataTable
    dtDefaultAvailable = ViewState("vsDefaultAvailable")

    Dim dtDefaultActive As New DataTable
    dtDefaultActive = ViewState("vsDefaultActive")

    Dim dtDefaultAmount As New DataTable
    ViewState("vsDefaultAmounts") = dtDefaultAmount

    For Each rowAvailable In dtDefaultAvailable.Rows
        Dim maxAccount = rowAvailable("MaxAccount").ToString()

        'For Each rowActive In dtDefaultActive.Rows
        'Dim ID = rowAvailable("ID").ToString()
        'Dim countID = ID.Count

    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not how I'd do it, but:

```
For Each rowAvailable as DataRow In dtDefaultAvailable.Rows
    Dim maxAccount = DirectCast(rowAvailable("MaxAccount"), Integer) 'it's an int, right?

    'step 2 and 3
    rowAvailable("AccountTotal") = maxAccount - dtDefaultActive.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Count(Function(r) r("ID").Equals(rowAvailable("ID")))

Next
```

As for how I'd do it:

- Create a DataSet type file
- Inside the visual designer create a datatable for Available and a datatable for Active
- Create a DataRelation where Active is a child of Available (Available ID is PK, Active.AvailableId is FK)
- Create a column in Available with an Expression of `[MaxAccount] - COUNT(Child.Id)`

[image]

Strongly typed datatables designed visually are a lot nicer to work with in code. Were your datatables strongly typed, the code would look like:

```
For Each rowAvailable In dtDefaultAvailable
    
    'step 2 and 3
    rowAvailable.AccountTotal = rowAvailable.MaxAccount - dtDefaultActive.Count(Function(r) r.ID = rowAvailable.ID)

Next
```

Much less messy when everything isn't an object, accessed by a string and needing casting.. And Intellisense works..